# Java EE simple login

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, authentication

I'm new to Java EE and does not really know how a login system should be implemented. Let say i have a mysql database with the table user and it got the columns username and password. How should i implement a secure login system? By secure I mean basic web security like hashed password and SSL connection when I send the password.

I look at [form based login](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html) but i can understand how it is suppose to get the data from the database by the built in page j_security_check? Don't i need to define connection string somehow and where do i define to use hash and SSL then?

I'm using tomcat v7.0.

Comment: how do you protect your URL ? this Q invites a broad topic of discussion

Comment: What do you mean by URL protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing: don't store passwords in database. You can store hashes.

Here's a simple way:

1. Add a form with fields username and password.
2. Create a session scoped managed bean called as an example User.
3. Create properties username and password in the bean (don't forget about accessors).
4. Bind form with properties you have created (as an example in JSF #{userBean.username}).
5. Create a method in the bean called authorize.
6. Bind the method with submit button on the form.
7. In authorize method create hash of password and try to find a row in users table which has username and password from the form.
8. On success redirect to another page, null the password field and use username field to recognize who is logged in.

It's the most simple way of implementing authorization in Java EE I can imagine.

Put a form like this one:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
    <h:inputText maxlength="255" size="20" tabindex="10" value="#{userBean.login}"
                    styleClass="inputField" id="username"/>
    <h:inputSecret maxlength="255" size="20" tabindex="20"
                     value="#{userBean.password}" styleClass="inputField" id="password"/>
    <h:commandButton value="login"
                                 action="#{userBean.validate}" id="submit"/>
</h:form>
```

And managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {
    private User user;
    private String login;
    private String password;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.user = new User();
    }

    public String validate() {
        // Validate given login and password here
        // When user seems to be valid assign it to this.user and return "/someFileForAuthorizedUsers.xhtml";
        this.login = null;
        this.password = null;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Don't forget about accessors. JSF needs them.